# How to always keep "Line wrap" checked in Chrome's view source?

Tags: google-chrome

I want this `Line wrap` checkbox to always be checked:

[image]

Is there a way or setting to do that?

Comment: Try the extension [Syntaxtic!](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/syntaxtic/cgjalgdhmbpaacnnejmodfinclbdgaci).

Comment: I tried it. But changed nothing in my view-source code.

Comment: @Destroy666 yes thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such option anywhere in Chrome. Extensions also can't modify that page for security reasons.

Extensions can however add their own pages to check source code of pages. For example, [View Renderered Source](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/view-rendered-source/ejgngohbdedoabanmclafpkoogegdpob/related?hl=en) uses word wrapping by default, there should also be a bunch of alternatives if you don't need the rendered source functionality.